# Avoid document.ready() using RequireJS and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Using RequireJS and Backbone, is it possible to avoid the classic call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

I just want to know if I can avoid it, if I am using RequireJS and Backbone. How is it possible to avoid that call?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually you don't need this using require.js

1st

```
<script data-main="main.js"  src="path/require.js"></script>
```

On main file you could have something like this:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: [
            'underscore',
            'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery              : 'path/jquery',
        underscore          : 'path/underscore',
        backbone            : 'path/backbone'
    }
});

require(
    [
    'backbone',
    'router'
    ],
    function (Backbone, Router) {
        var router = new Router();
    }
);
```

Comment: yes but the require function at the bottom is invoked after all the scripts have loaded but not necessarily before the DOM is fully loaded. the RequireJS docs warn about this. From what I can tell it is much better practice to put var router =... inside a $(document).ready() block...otherwise you have a race condition between which loads faster the DOM or the scripts.